# Dividing values within dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe below. My goal is to take the "Mean" of each unique "Clone"/"Primer" set and divide by the "Mean" from the "Gen" value of 0. For example, for the "Clone" elements with a value of 100 and "Primer" of HC, I want to perform 0.6417179/0.6417179, 0.6553668/0.6417179, 0.6106679/0.6417179, etc. Same goes for the LC, as well as the other clones. Ultimately, I would like to insert these values to a new column in the dataframe. I know I could probably do this with mapply, but was looking for a simpler method. The first five rows of data should look like new.data.

```
data <- structure(list(Sample.Num = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Sample 01", 
"Sample 02", "Sample 03", "Sample 04", "Sample 05", "Sample 06", 
"Sample 07", "Sample 08", "Sample 09", "Sample 10", "Sample 11", 
"Sample 12", "Sample 13", "Sample 14", "Sample 15", "Sample 16", 
"Sample 17", "Sample 18", "Sample 19", "Sample 20"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample.Name = 1:20, Mean = c(0.641717918200621, 0.732758814939348, 
    0.655366791432443, 0.711143128584475, 0.610667936146982, 
    0.687271981619014, 0.618062095091066, 0.687031960480684, 
    0.411787349743996, 0.546062868229852, 0.415749282456685, 
    0.518132889723448, 0.389048523492206, 0.499694202691936, 
    0.388389111597721, 0.484997103717381, 0.828167703325264, 
    1.06355991484498, 1.35633865722435, 1.83226419032622), SD = c(0.0182658841978206, 
    0.0215796881079389, 0.025765124311367, 0.0209344970091099, 
    0.0123992922337212, 0.00595663805702379, 0.0144295473675257, 
    0.0113668742903368, 0.00464092492744697, 0.00900809118776624, 
    0.00805595964358455, 0.00523626400646404, 0.0026802389683131, 
    0.00731653117590531, 0.00566027602189678, 0.00868682006010785, 
    0.683066526651359, 0.863371994277613, 0.00291361279231728, 
    0.0361119112674108), Primer = c("HC", "LC", "HC", "LC", "HC", 
    "LC", "HC", "LC", "HC", "LC", "HC", "LC", "HC", "LC", "HC", 
    "LC", "HC", "LC", "HC", "LC"), Clone = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 
    100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 400, 
    400, 400, 400, 400), Gen = c(0, 0, 20, 20, 40, 40, 60, 60, 
    80, 80, 0, 0, 20, 20, 40, 40, 60, 60, 80, 80)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")

new.data <- structure(list(Sample.Num = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Sample 01", 
"Sample 02", "Sample 03", "Sample 04", "Sample 05", "Sample 06", 
"Sample 07", "Sample 08", "Sample 09", "Sample 10", "Sample 11", 
"Sample 12", "Sample 13", "Sample 14", "Sample 15", "Sample 16", 
"Sample 17", "Sample 18", "Sample 19", "Sample 20"), class = "factor"), 
    Sample.Name = 1:5, Mean = c(0.641717918200621, 0.732758814939348, 
    0.655366791432443, 0.711143128584475, 0.610667936146982), 
    SD = c(0.0182658841978206, 0.0215796881079389, 0.025765124311367, 
    0.0209344970091099, 0.0123992922337212), Primer = c("HC", 
    "LC", "HC", "LC", "HC"), Clone = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100
    ), Gen = c(0, 0, 20, 20, 40), New = c(1, 1, 1.02, 0.97, 0.95
    )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match` to get corresponding `Mean` value for `Gen = 0` in each `Clone` and `Primer` combination.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Clone, Primer) %>%
  mutate(New = Mean/Mean[match(0, Gen)])

# Sample.Num Sample.Name  Mean      SD Primer Clone   Gen    New
#   <fct>            <int> <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Sample 01            1 0.642 0.0183  HC       100     0  1    
# 2 Sample 01            2 0.733 0.0216  LC       100     0  1    
# 3 Sample 02            3 0.655 0.0258  HC       100    20  1.02 
# 4 Sample 02            4 0.711 0.0209  LC       100    20  0.971
# 5 Sample 03            5 0.611 0.0124  HC       100    40  0.952
# 6 Sample 03            6 0.687 0.00596 LC       200    40 NA    
# 7 Sample 04            7 0.618 0.0144  HC       200    60 NA    
# 8 Sample 04            8 0.687 0.0114  LC       200    60 NA    
# 9 Sample 05            9 0.412 0.00464 HC       200    80 NA 
#...  
#...
```

This returns `NA` for combinations where no `Gen = 0` is present.

Comment: I was trying to remember the group_by function, but it slipped my mind. Thanks!